# How to call function with many different types?

Tags: generics, types, rust, enums, overloading

Let's suppose we have the following enum:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum CustomType {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),
}
```

In order to have a function that behave the same way for different parameters types:

```rust
fn my_function(my_param: &CustomType){
  // logic to use "my_param"
  // my_param is used for the handlebars crate, therefore requires to be Serde Serializable
 let source = // ...
 handlebars.render_template(&source, my_param).unwrap();
}
```

And we want to call such function in different parts of our program like follows:

```rust
fn function_a(bar: &Bar){
  my_function(CustomType::Bar(bar.clone()));
}

fn function_b(foo: &Foo){
  my_function(CustomType::Foo(foo.clone()));
}
```

This code works, but I really don't like it, as I have to `.clone()`. I already tried to pass only the reference but it won't work for the enum.

Is this the right way of doing it in Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `CustomType` take references instead of owned values if you don't want to call `clone`:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Foo(String);

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Bar(String);

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum CustomType<'a> {
    Foo(&'a Foo),
    Bar(&'a Bar),
}

fn my_function(my_param: &CustomType) {
    println!("serialized {}", serde_json::to_string(&my_param).unwrap());
}

fn func_foo(foo: &Foo) {
    my_function(&CustomType::Foo(foo));
}

fn func_bar(bar: &Bar) {
    my_function(&CustomType::Bar(bar));
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo("Foo".to_string());
    let bar = Bar("Bar".to_string());
    func_foo(&foo);
    func_bar(&bar);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7068b394c863ed12501a9115ca20ac5c)

However if the only reason `CustomType` exists is so you can pass `Serializable` types into `my_function` then it'd probably be simpler to just make `my_function` generic and accept any `Serializable` references:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Foo(String);

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Bar(String);

fn my_function<T: Serialize>(my_param: &T) {
    println!("serialized {}", serde_json::to_string(my_param).unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo("Foo".to_string());
    let bar = Bar("Bar".to_string());
    my_function(&foo);
    my_function(&bar);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=efbb118968d16b5b9b46f0ba29a9bbbe)

Comment: Yes! The reason for `CustomType` was exactly for that purpose. I didn't know you can just `<T: Serialize>` stuff (I tried with `<T>` before but stopped as it was not Serializable)